# Where does Eclipse store settings and plugins in userdir?

Tags: eclipse, unix, plugins, installation

I've just installed a new Linux distro on my box and want to move my Eclipse home from the old `/home/username/` to my new one. Because I changed the desktop, I don't want to copy all hidden folders from `~/`. So which directories do I need copy in order to have all my installed plugins?

I've already copied `~/.eclipse/` and it definitely contains files related to the plugins but Eclipse won't load them. Any hints?

Comment: Are you using a packaged version of Eclipse? Like the one provided by Ubuntu or Debian? Because that would nearly certainly change things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've eventually found the directory containing all that stuff by accident. Somehow we broke it and Eclipse refused to start on my coworker's computer:-)

See `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins` or wherever your workspace resides.

Comment: That seems to be just the config files for the plugins.. but not the jar files themselves

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Eclipse stores its plugins in its installation directory (`eclipse`). They might reside in `eclipse/plugins` or `eclipse/dropins`. You can copy the whole `eclipse` directory from your old box.

Comment: This is what I had already done and it's obviously not enough…

Comment: Try running `eclipse -clean` (http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm).

Comment: `eclipse clean` didn't help either. Yesterday in the evening I gave up and started installing my plugins (just a few) from scratch. Unfortunately I couldn't finished because EPIC website is down. So any hints are still appreciated.